# Paragraph indent in marginpar

Tags: formatting, indentation, marginpar

I use `memoir` and defined my own version of margin notes. I would like margin notes consisting of multiple paragraphs to have each paragraph except the first one to be indented. However, I can't figure out how to prevent indentation of the first paragraph. The MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\setstocksize{11.0in}{8.5in}
\settrimmedsize{11.0in}{8.5in}{*}
\setlength{\trimtop}{0.0in}
\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth}
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth}
\settypeblocksize{9.0in}{4.87in}{*}
\setlrmargins{*}{1.0in}{*}
\setulmargins{1.0in}{*}{*}
\setmarginnotes{17pt}{1.5in}{\onelineskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%% side notes
\marginparmargin{left}
\newcommand{\mysidenote}[1]{%
  \strictpagecheck\marginpar{\setlength{\parindent}{1.0em}\footnotesize #1}%
}

\checkandfixthelayout
\begin{document}
\section{A Section}
\lipsum[1]
\mysidenote{
  \lipsum[1]
  \lipsum[2]
}%
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE:** David's suggestion works as desired except if I use `\mysidenote` from within a `\paragraph`. The following modified MWE shows this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\setstocksize{11.0in}{8.5in}
\settrimmedsize{11.0in}{8.5in}{*}
\setlength{\trimtop}{0.0in}
\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth}
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth}
\settypeblocksize{9.0in}{4.87in}{*}
\setlrmargins{*}{1.0in}{*}
\setulmargins{1.0in}{*}{*}
\setmarginnotes{17pt}{1.5in}{\onelineskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%% side notes
\marginparmargin{left}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mysidenote}[1]{%
  \strictpagecheck\marginpar{\setlength{\parindent}{1.0em}\footnotesize
  \@afterheading #1}%
}
\makeatother

\checkandfixthelayout
\begin{document}
\section{A Section}
\lipsum[1]
\mysidenote{\lipsum[1]}

\paragraph{A Paragraph}
\lipsum[1]
\mysidenote{\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

The first `\mysidenote` works as expected (no indentation), but the second one does not (is indented). What I would like is an improved definition of `\mysidenote` that works in all section environments without my having to use \noindent in `\paragraph`.

Comment: I seem to get the desired result if I add `\noindent\ignorespaces` after `\footnotesize`. The `%` after the closing brace is not necessary, as `\sidenote` takes care of it

Comment: Your suggestion seems to be similar to John's, but David suggested that adding \noindent was not a good idea, which is why I did not comment on your reply so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best not to use `\noindent` to suppress indentation as it causes problems with white space and especially blank lines at the start. You can use `\@afterheading` which is the mechanism latex uses to suppress indentation after headings.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\setstocksize{11.0in}{8.5in}
\settrimmedsize{11.0in}{8.5in}{*}
\setlength{\trimtop}{0.0in}
\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth}
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth}
\settypeblocksize{9.0in}{4.87in}{*}
\setlrmargins{*}{1.0in}{*}
\setulmargins{1.0in}{*}{*}
\setmarginnotes{17pt}{1.5in}{\onelineskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%% side notes
\marginparmargin{left}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mysidenote}[1]{%
  \strictpagecheck\marginpar{\setlength{\parindent}{1.0em}\footnotesize
   \@afterindentfalse\@afterheading #1}%
}
\makeatother
\checkandfixthelayout
\begin{document}
\section{A Section}
\lipsum[1]
\mysidenote{
  \lipsum[1]
  \lipsum[2]
}%
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: That did the trick for my MWE as well as solving the problem I mentioned in my comment to John. However, in my actual tex files, it occasionally leads to side notes in which the first line is indented. I have not yet been able to isolate when this happens, however.

Comment: I found out when the modified \mysidenote does not work (when used in a \paragraph) and edited my question and MWE accordingly.

Comment: @user1362373 sorry I forgot `\@afterindentfalse` see update.

Answer (score 2):

It's a simple fix, but I never thought of it myself until I saw it being used in a sty file.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\setstocksize{11.0in}{8.5in}
\settrimmedsize{11.0in}{8.5in}{*}
\setlength{\trimtop}{0.0in}
\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth}
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth}
\settypeblocksize{9.0in}{4.87in}{*}
\setlrmargins{*}{1.0in}{*}
\setulmargins{1.0in}{*}{*}
\setmarginnotes{17pt}{1.5in}{\onelineskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%% side notes
\marginparmargin{left}
\newcommand{\mysidenote}[1]{%
  \strictpagecheck\marginpar{\setlength{\parindent}{1.0em}\footnotesize
  \noindent #1}%
}

\checkandfixthelayout
\begin{document}
\section{A Section}
\lipsum[1]
\mysidenote{% to prevent an extra space
  \lipsum[1]
  \lipsum[2]
}%
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the trick for simple margin notes, but for more complex ones (I haven't quite figured out yet what exactly is causing the problems), I get a sudden vertical shift in the lines if I keep the \ignorespaces). Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Okay, lose the \ignorespaces and just remember to put a % after {

Answer (score 2):

I had two answers, the first being the same as John Kormylo's, which indents all paragraphs except the first (note the `%` in `\mysidenote{%`).

The second answer for if you want a note consisting of a single paragraph to be indented is not to modify your `\mysidenote` macro but in any multiparagraph sidenote to put `\noindent` before the first paragraph of any multiparagraph note. For example:

```
\mysidenote{%
  \noindent\lipsum[1] % not indented
  \lipsum[2]          % indented
}
```

or

```
\mysidenote{%
  \lipsum[1]          % indented
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can avoid using `\noindent` if you initially set `\parindent` to zero and increase it to the desired value (`1em`) right after the first token of `\mysidenote`'s argument has been processed:

```
\newcommand{\mysidenote}[1]{%
  \strictpagecheck\marginpar{\parindent0em\footnotesize\mysidenotei#1}}
\newcommand{\mysidenotei}[1]{#1\parindent1em}
```

[image: output]

#### Complete code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
  \setstocksize{11.0in}{8.5in}
  \settrimmedsize{11.0in}{8.5in}{*}
  \setlength{\trimtop}{0.0in}
  \setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth}
  \addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth}
  \settypeblocksize{9.0in}{4.87in}{*}
  \setlrmargins{*}{1.0in}{*}
  \setulmargins{1.0in}{*}{*}
  \setmarginnotes{17pt}{1.5in}{\onelineskip}
  \marginparmargin{left}

\newcommand{\mysidenote}[1]{\strictpagecheck\marginpar{\parindent0em\footnotesize\mysidenotei#1}}
\newcommand{\mysidenotei}[1]{#1\parindent1em}

\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A Section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\mysidenote{%
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 

  Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
}%
Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.

Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
\end{document}
```